# Can I upgrade from 10.04LTS to 12.04LTS with the alternate CD?

Tags: 10.04, 12.04, release-upgrade

I want to upgrade 33 computers from 10.04LTS to 12.04LTS, but with my internet connection I cannot upgrade 33 computers, so I want to upgrade on an offline installation mode, so I have heard about the alternate CD image that is suitable for upgrading, but my question is can I use it on my USB drive for upgrading???

Answer (score 2):

From [the release notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuDesktop#PrecisePangolin.2BAC8-ReleaseNotes.2BAC8-CommonInfrastructure-1.Upgrades):

> Upgrades from Ubuntu 10.04 LTS to 12.04 LTS do not work using the alternate CD or the server CD as a package repository. It is recommended that users running Ubuntu 10.04 LTS wait for the 12.04.1 LTS point release, scheduled for July, before upgrading.

Answer (score 0):

The only way for LTS-to-LTS upgrade I found was

```
do-release-upgrade -m desktop -d
```